# Loops to populate JUnit Parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, junit, junit4, nested-loops

I am trying to extract individual URLs from an array list and have them act as the arguments for a series of JUnit tests. However, thus far I have been unable to do so.

This project focuses on web testing, and the method I am using retrieves the HTTP status code for a given URL.

The code below is the parameters section from the JUnit Test. It accepts the URL and Expected value as inputs, and compares them to the actual vale to determine whether or not each passes.

```
        @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> testData(){


        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{"http://google.com",200}, {"http://yahoo.com", 404}};


        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
```

Does anybody have any experience on looping through list arrays with parametrized JUnit testing? Ex)

```
Object [][] data = new Object [][]{{urlArray.get(0), statusArray.get(0},....{urlArray.get(i), statusArray.get(i)}}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Full code below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before; 
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized; 
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;



@RunWith(Parameterized.class)

public class CodeFinderTest extends CodeFinder {

private String url; 
private int expected; 


public CodeFinderTest(String url, int expected){
    this.url = url; 
    this.expected = expected; 

}


CodeFinder instance;
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        instance = new CodeFinder(); 
}


    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> testData(){


        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{"http://google.com",200}, {"http://yahoo.com", 404}};


        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFinder() throws IOException{
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, instance.status(url)); 
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you post the full source of your test class? Are you using the correct test runner, i.e. @RunWith(Parameterized.class)? Here's also an example for [parameterized tests](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/).

Comment: Proposed changes were made. Full source code can now be found above. @John

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more what exactly goes wrong? Why is your test class extending CodeFinder?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong, persay, but I haven't been able to implement a loop to create an array under "@Parameters". Using the code above, I could manually enter the values, but when I tried to store them in an array and pass them in, I was unable to. @John

Answer (score 1):

The method that provides test data is a real method. Hence you can do this:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> testData(){
  List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
  Iterator<String> itUrl = urlArray.iterator();
  Iterator<Integer> itStatus = statusArray.iterator();
  while (itUrl.hasNext())
    data.add(new Object [] {itUrl.next(), itStatus.next()});
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input Stefan, but I have a question about the return statement. I have been having trouble with <object>/Collection<object> compatibility. I get an error that says the types do not match (cannot convert from object[] to collection <object[]> ). Have any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: The toArray() call in the last line was wrong. I corrected the example.